# I have JSON data, of type Array of Dictionaries. How do I use Codable protocol to decode it?

Tags: swift, rest, api, dictionary, parsing

```
[
{
"status":"ok"
},
{
"feeds":[
{
"id":"68",
"userby":"1",
"usertype":"Registered    Students",
"content":"test",
"total_likes":"0",
"total_comments":"0",
"video_url":"(Some_URL)",
"image_url":"",
"created_date":"2019-06-26    20:34:02",
"modified_date":"0000-00-00    00:00:00",
"is_active":"Y",
"is_deleted":"N",
"feed_id":"68",
"user_name":"M    Y",
"profile_image":"(some_URL)",
"is_liked":"N"
}, //And so on feed entries...! ]}]    



// The Structure I tried using. 

typealias FeedDataDict = [FeedData]

struct FeedData : Codable {
    var status : String
    var feeds : [Feed]

}


let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let content = try decoder.decode( FeedDataDict.self , from: data)
print ( content[0].feeds[0].id )
```

I tried adding the struct to array, and used index 0 to access it. however it throws issues at me, saying values at index were found nil.

I expect to collect all values present in Data.

Comment: seems sone issue in json...if you remove the `{
"status": "ok"
},` it could work

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your json is an array of dictionaries so if you do

```
do {
    let content = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [[String: Any]]
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Then content is an array where the first index contains `["status": "ok"]` and your second element is your feeds array

You can also use `Codable` by using a custom `init` in the `FeedData` struct

```
struct FeedData : Codable {
    var status : String?
    var feeds : [Feed]?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var values = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        let statusDict = try values.decode([String:String].self)
        status = statusDict["status"]
        let feedsDict = try values.decode([String:[Feed]].self)
        feeds = feedsDict["feeds"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add on some thing in @Sh_Khan's answer that your JSON data isn't in correct format though it will work but it should be in format like

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "feeds": [
    {
      "id": "68",
      "userby": "1",
      "usertype": "Registered    Students",
      "content": "test",
      "total_likes": "0",
      "total_comments": "0",
      "video_url": "https:\/\/medicalcosmetology.org.md-64.webhostbox.net\/adminpanel\/uploads\/feed\/videos\/V_20190514_1151392.mp4",
      "image_url": "",
      "created_date": "2019-06-26    20:34:02",
      "modified_date": "0000-00-00    00:00:00",
      "is_active": "Y",
      "is_deleted": "N",
      "feed_id": "68",
      "user_name": "M    Y",
      "profile_image": "https:\/\/medicalcosmetology.org.md-64.webhostbox.net\/adminpanel\/uploads\/user\/2eee0e67c31427fc5be42147ed9664b3.png",
      "is_liked": "N"
    }
  ]
}
```

Once you get correct JSON then try to parse it as below:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let content = try decoder.decode( FeedDataDict.self , from: data)
print ( content.feeds[0].id )
```

But if you don't want to change it then go with @Sh_Khan's answer.